# Error installing pg 1.2.3: Failed to build gem native extension. Ubuntu18.04

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have a problem with ruby bundle install. I tried a lot but nothing works for me:

The system I am using is Ubuntu 18.04.

I got an error message as below:

```
Fetching pg 1.2.3
Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I tried the following command:

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

and I got:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpq-dev is already the newest version (10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
```

Nothing works out. How can I install pg 1.2.3 successfully?

Comment: Have you checked mkmf.log? It should contain more details... (you could also share the details in the question)

Answer (score 3):

The way it worked for me (Mac OSX):

1. Download latest postgres (http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/);
2. After installation complete, open the folder /Library/PostgreSQL and check the version number within it (it was 12 in my case);
3. Either run (replace **x.y** by your version number of step 2)

`$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/bin gem install pg`

or

`$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/bin bundle install`

Best wishes!

Comment: All I needed to do was download the latest Postgres (I opted to install via Homebrew). Once installed I ran the `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` command again and it succeeded.